# How to simulate login in jsp?

Tags: jsp, request

I want to access billimage.jsp pages but it need authentication from login.jsp page. I must enter username and password to get authenticated.

What should i do to make some jsp simulate login andredirect to billimage.jsp and logged in  automatically??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Fiddler
2. Open it, make sure it sniffs http[s] traffic
3. Go to login page, signin
4. Look what fiddler captured -> should be kind of POST request with parameters as userName, password, maybe some more such as captcha, some antiforgery tokens
5. Response contains cookies if login was successfull, an probably has a redirect (browser uses that cookie to tell server that you've signed in already)
6. Repeat those steps programically
7. Profit!